# Overwriting mage core create.php

Tags: core

I'm attempting to overwrite `adminhtml/model/sales/order/create.php`, specifically `public function initFromOrderItem`.

Text output shows the function I've overwritten is not loading to the site.

In `app/etc/modules/GoddessDelivers_QObugfux.xml`

```
 <config>
     <modules>
         <GoddessDelivers_QObugfix> <!--  app/code/<codepool>/GoddessDelivers/QObugfix  -->
             <active>true</active>
             <codePool>local</codePool>
             <depends>
                 <Mage_Core />
             </depends>
         </GoddessDelivers_QObugfix>

     </modules>
 </config>
```

In `app/code/local/GoddessDelivers/QObugfix/etc/config.xml`

```
 <config>
     <modules>
         <GoddessDelivers_QObugfix>
             <version>0.0.0.1</version>
         </GoddessDelivers_QObugfix>
     </modules>
     <global>
         <adminhtml>
             <sales>
                 <order>
                     <rewrite>
                         <create>GoddessDelivers_QObugfix_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create</create>
                     </rewrite>
                 </order>
             </sales>
         </adminhtml>
     </global>

 </config>
```

In `app/code/local/GoddessDelivers/QObugfix/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php`:

```
 class GoddessDelivers_QObugfix_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create
 extends Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create {
     public function initFromOrderItem(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item $orderItem, $qty = null)
     {
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the `<models>` node in your config. Your node nesting also needs fixing.

```
<config>
    <modules>
         <GoddessDelivers_QObugfix>
             <version>0.0.0.1</version>
         </GoddessDelivers_QObugfix>
     </modules>
     <global>
         <models>
             <adminhtml>
                 <rewrite>
                     <sales_order_create>GoddessDelivers_QObugfix_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create</rewrite>
                 </adminhtml>
             </models>
         </global> 
 </config>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Typo in file name app/etc/modules/GoddessDelivers_QObugf**u**x.xml; probably you meant `app/etc/modules/GoddessDelivers_QObugfix.xml`
2. In file `app/etc/modules/GoddessDelivers_QObugf*u*x.xml` you should set a the module you're overwriting from as a dependency, so `<depends><Mage_Adminhtml /></depends>`
3. In config.xml the path is `/config/global/models/adminhtml`, so you should have:

> ```
> <config>
>   <global>
>     <models>
>       <adminhtml>
>         <rewrite>
>           <sales_order_create>GoddessDelivers_QObugfix_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create</sales_order_create>
>         </rewrite>
>       </adminhtml>
>     </models>
>   </global>
> </config>
> ```

4. The modes path is non-standard; should be `code/local/GoddessDelivers/QObugfix/Model/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Create.php` and the class name should reflect the path.